# Safari 5.7.1 not allowing third party cookies

Tags: java, jsp, iframe, browser, safari

Safari is not allowing third party cookies . I tried by setting response header in JSP as:

```
response.setHeader("P3P","CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT'");
```

It works fine with all browsers except Safari.

Answer (score -1):

Safari blocks third party cookies by default.